# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil for iPhone. Connecting one class in two storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to use one class (DetailCell) for both iPhone and iPad storyboard.
I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";
        DetailCell * detailCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (detailCell == nil) {
            detailCell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];
        }
        //cell customization here...
    return detailCell;
}
```

It perfectly works for iPad but does not for iPhone! All identifiers and connections and class set properly. I've also tried to wipe cells in both boards and create new. What I actually have:

on iPad:

I'm getting the cell in the deque so it does not enter to if and returns cell as needed.

on iPhone:

deque returns nil, going to if, it returns DetailCell but cusomization for it does not work. (all outlets are nils before and after setting values)
What can be the reason for this behavior?

P.S both on iOS5 and iOS6

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns cell, only when any of the cells with the given identifier went offscreen and queued.  Are you sure that this is happening in your case ?

Comment: @nkongara in ios6 it returns cell anyway. But on iphone it creates cell with init as many times as I have rows! And still empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";

```
DetailCell * detailCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (detailCell == nil)
{
    detailCell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[DetailCell class]])
        cell = (DetailCell *)oneObject;
}
//cell customization here...
return detailCell;
```

Comment: You are creating 2 cells inside that if block. The first has the same problem as the OP and the second just get's discarded immediately for no reason :/. If you correct the second to correctly assign to `detailCell` instead of `cell` then you still have made a cell for no reason by `alloc/init*` to begin with

Comment: Sorry but this code makes no sense..more over I use storyboards